# List all files changed by a particular user in subversion

Tags: svn

Is it possible to get a list of all files modified/added/deleted by a particular user?

The goal is to get an idea of what a user did for the day (or date range).

Comment: Is there an equivalent to cvs monitor for svn?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's an example, using the [svn log command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) and [linux sed command](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=linux+sed+command), with your username, 'blankman':

```
svn log | sed -n '/blankman/,/-----$/ p'
```

If you're looking to obtain this information with continual reports, using a project like [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/), which Patrick mentioned, is very useful.  If you're using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), there is a [StatSCM plugin](http://stat-scm.sourceforge.net/) which will generate this information on your project site.

Comment: @JamieMcNaught, --username is for specifying which user to authenticate with.

Comment: @sudarkoff Yup, you're right, removed it as it's incorrect. No idea why I thought that worked.

Comment: There is `svn log --search` beginning from SVN 1.8! http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#svn-log-search

Answer (score 19):

There is no need to bother with `grep`, `sed`, etc starting from Subversion 1.8. [The release introduced `--search` option that you can use with `svn log` command](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#svn-log-search)!

The options allows you to search your repository history for:

- revision's author (`svn:author` unversioned property),
- date (`svn:date` unversioned property),
- log message text (`svn:log` unversioned property),
- and paths affected by the particular revision.

See [SVNBook 1.8 | `svn log` command-line reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html).

Answer (score 7):

Shek's response helped me with what I needed to do, but I found I got more accurate results with the following tweak:

```
svn log | sed -n '/ | blankman | /,/-----$/ p'
```

Otherwise, the list includes commits made by others that simply reference me by name.

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply use the tortoise SVN ?

Totoise SVN --> Show Log
Add the user id on top left for which you would like to see the list of changes

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
svn log  | grep YOUR_USERNAME_HERE | awk '{print $1}' | sed s/r//g | xargs -I $ svn diff --summarize -c $ | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. We use [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) for our subversion reports, and one of the reports it does is commits by developer.

TortiseSVN also lets you look at log messages by date for authors.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the date-range version

> svn log -v -r{"2011-01-01 00:00:00"}:{"2011-02-18 00:00:00"}| sed -n '/russenreaktor/,/-----$/ p'

Answer (score 3):

I found this useful command to find a list of modified files by a given user:

```
svn log -v -r{2012-08-01}:HEAD 
| awk '/^r[0-9]+ / {user=$3} /./ {if (user=="username") {print}}'
| grep -E "^   M|^   G|^   A|^   D|^   C|^   U" 
| awk '{print $2}'
| sort | uniq
```

And the [link to the original article](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2362/gets-all-files-committed-to-svn-by-a-particular-user-since-a-particular-date).

Comment: This one actually only listed all files touched by a specific user, which answers the question. Many of the other answers were not this accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small script to show which files were changed by a certain user between revisions.

```
#!/bin/bash
# @param $1: Start revision
# @param $2: End revision
# @param $3: User
#
# Example: svn_scapegoat.sh 1000:HEAD jdoe

svn_changed()
{
    svn blame --revision $1:$2 -- $4 | grep -E "^ [0-9]* *${3} "
}

svn diff --revision $1:$2 --summarize | \
cut -c9- | \
while read path
do
    if [ -n "$(svn_changed $1 $2 $3 $path)" ]
    then
        echo "$3 changed $path"
    else
        echo "Someone else changed $path"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score -3):

In order to see the list all files changed by a particular user in subversion for a particular directory structure, then first you need go to the that directory structure and on the right side of directory panel do a right click..
then,
go to Show Log-->on top most left corner we get filter option.

henceforth by putting the name of user you can see all the files changed by that particular user in the bottom panel.

Comment: The svn itself is command line based. Your suggestions are related to some third party graphical interface around it