# Listing changes made by a particular user in svn using windows command prompt

Tags: svn

I have the same requirement as asked in the question [List all files changed by a particular user in subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341310/list-all-files-changed-by-a-particular-user-in-subversion).

I want to display all the changes made by a particular user in SVN (by date)using windows command prompt, so that we can include it in a batch file.

Are there any ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have and can use Powershell :

```
 svn log -v http://mb-unit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk | Select-String "author"
```

In a batch file you can do like:

```
@powershell -command "svn log -v http://mb-unit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk | Select-String 'author'"
```

Tools like `grep`, `findstr` ( common on Windows ) can also be used. ALso, even `sed` as mentioned in the answer that you have linked to, is available for windows ( through `Msys` for example - http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys )