# svn changes by user history

Tags: svn

Is there a script which goes out and finds out all the changes made by a user and shows them as a diff, allowing me to specify key words in the diff text in the entire SVN history for all files in all sub-branches.
For example, I would like to see all changes made between two dates, by a user in which the word "EJB" was specified.
I looked at several scripts out there, e.g.
[List all files changed by a particular user in subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341310/list-all-files-changed-by-a-particular-user-in-subversion)
but they don't show the path nor the diffs.
Microsoft SourceSafe has such a reporting tool, so I'd think that someone has done something for SVN already.
Sorry if I seem ignorant, I really don't understand sed/awk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20398202/960558 and|or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4439780/960558

Answer (score 0):

I use Tortoise Svn http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

In the repo browser, you can right click folder and show log. There is a filter for searching for things such as "EJB", and you can "Compare with previous revision" on any file, which will open up the built in diff tool

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to see all changes made between two dates, by a user in which the word "EJB" was specified

- If "EJB" is **NOT** a part of filename (part of username or log-message) and SVN 1.8+ used

  1. List of all such reisions `svn log -q -r {STARTDATE}:{ENDDATE} --search EJB`
  2. Changes for each revision from the above list `svn diff -c REV` in cycle
- If "EJB" is (can be) a part of filename

  1. List of all such reisions `svn log -q -r -v {STARTDATE}:{ENDDATE} --search EJB`
  2. *Same as above*